# Should users be able to flag comments as obsolete that they have previously upvoted?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, flagging

I understand why I cannot flag a comment I've upvoted. When I upvote a comment, it means I think it is of especially high quality.

But an especially high quality comment can become obsolete (for example, if a question is posted that contains and expands on the same information, or if it requests additional details subsequently provided by the OP). Then, it seems to me that I should be able to flag the comment as obsolete, even if I cannot flag it as anything else.

Is there any good reason why we cannot flag comments as obsolete that we have previously upvoted?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Workaround: What I did when I saw that was flag the post with a comment saying "hey, please destroy all these comments they are obsolete".

To answer the "why" part, comments are really second class citizens - questions and answers are name of the game, so technically comments shouldn't exist at all.

That being said, just flag the post saying

> hey, please delete all the comments, they are inaccurate or too chatty.

And it shall be done.

In fact:

> Comments are disposable on Stack Exchange. They can be deleted without warning or review by moderators, participants, or other users. If you have something important to say, say it in an answer. – Shog9♦ [yesterday](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1282/david-zaslavsky-moved-comments-no-good#comment3033_1282)

(I copy/pasted that here, since comments can be well... deleted without warning or review... ironic isn't it?)

Comment: That comments are "second class citizens," is only more reason why it should be easier to suggest them for deletion as obsolete even after one has upvoted them.

Comment: @EliahKagan yes, agreed. I wish it was possible, and it has been discussed before, I just can't find the reasoning.