# Can comments not part of a discussion still be flagged as "too chatty"?

Tags: discussion, support, comments, flagging

Is it sometimes appropriate to flag comments as "too chatty" even if they are not actually part of discussion taking place in comments?

Here are some made up examples where I would be tempted to flag comments as "too chatty" even when they don't appear in a sequence of comments:

1. (in a question about the alternate CD) `+1 the alternate CD rocks!`
2. (in a question about switching from gedit to emacs) `Yeah gedit is not powerful enough, good luck switching.`

Or should such comments be flagged as unconstructive?

A real-world example of this is currently [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100965/how-to-uninstall-windows), though of course it may disappear (which I why I gave made-up examples).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More or less, just flag them.

[As I stated earlier](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/3118/6005), comments are second class citizens, and may be destroyed at any point in time. As such, pointless comments that don't add anything to the discussion can be safely flagged as too chatty.

Comment: I would add that they can also be safely flagged as not constructive.